# pip install ecos errors with "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."

Tags: python, visual-c++, installation, ecos

I am trying to install the fancyimpute in my anaconda using pip install. but the error shows fail to install the ecos due to " Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required." the link provided is expired. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

```
(py36) C:\Users\chenl>pip install ecos
Collecting ecos
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/b4/988b15513b13e8ea2eac65e97d84221ac515a735a93f046e2a2a3d7863fc/ecos-2.0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6 in c:\users\chenl\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages (from ecos) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.9 in c:\users\chenl\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages (from ecos) (1.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: ecos
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ecos ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\chenl\anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\chenl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-omudd71s\\ecos\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\chenl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7kzas5zm --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying src\ecos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_ecos' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for ecos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download from this page: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ecos
Copy to folder near your venv, activate it and run:

```
pip install ecos‑*.whl
```